# MAC OS X: Set external USB camera resolution with AVCaptureSession's sessionPreset doesn't work

Tags: macos, avfoundation, avcapturesession

I am trying to set the camera's resolution for the capture session using this:

```
[session setSessionPreset:AVCaptureSessionPresetLow];  // or any others resolutions
```

It doesn't seem to make any difference.  It always uses the highest resolution the camera can offer.  This is a UVC compliant USB camera and wasn't made by Apple.

Question: Can setSessionPreset apply to external USB non-Apple camera?  Or my problem is something else?

Edit:
I also tried this test:

```
if ([session canSetSessionPreset:AVCaptureSessionPresetLow])
{
    NSLog(@"can presetlow");    // this part got called.
    [session beginConfiguration];
    session.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetLow;
    [session commitConfiguration];
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"no, can't presetlow");
}
```

Bounty question:  How to set the camera resolution in this case?

Comment: What camera are you using, specifically?

Comment: No brand name... One of those from eBay.

Comment: my recommendation: start with a camera that is known to do what you want, if you have the means

Answer (score 2):

It may not be possible, depending on the camera.  UVC compatible does not mean that all features are supported.

http://www.mac-compatible-web-cam.com/?ID=McRmr2

A work-around, depending on your application, might be to take the high-res image and convert it to lower res in your code.

Comment: I have been doing the capture and converting it to lower resolution.  But due to the nature of the app, I tried to avoid that process as much as possible.